# mysql group by How to optimize and improve query speed？

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT `time`,count(uid) as log 
FROM ( 
      SELECT distinct uid,
      FROM_UNIXTIME(createtime,"%Y-%m-%d") as time FROM `yq_user_log` 
      WHERE `createtime` BETWEEN 1535126400 AND 1537891199 AND `type` = 'login'  
     ) a GROUP BY time
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Do you have indexes on the relevant columns? Have you tried using a JOIN rather than a sub-query? Without knowing how your database is set up it's going to be impossible to offer anything other than general suggestions.

Comment: How long does the query last ?

Comment: 1s+   300000+  row  data

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you don't even need to subquery:

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(createtime, '%Y-%m-%d') AS time,
    COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS log
FROM yq_user_log
WHERE createtime BETWEEN 1535126400 AND 1537891199 AND type = 'login'
GROUP BY time;
```

I'm not sure that any index would help much here, because you are grouping by a function of a column.  This would preclude an index helping with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: thanks ! Direct query will slow down for 0. seconds.